# Cant boot from Windows 10 DVD

Tags: boot, dvd

I downloaded windows 10 iso yesterday and burnt it to a DVD using ImgBurn..The burn was succesful but when I try to boot my computer from the dvd I get a blinking underscore at the top of a black screen..When I remove the DVD, it boots normally and the PC starts ( but I get BSOD )..What could be the issue?

Note: My new HDD failed so I decided to use my old one and I plugged it to my new PC. The computer started but I got BSOD. So I decided to format it and install Windows 10.

Comment: Use Rufus and be sure you make it EFI compatible your current disk wasn't created correctly

Comment: @Ramhound Rufus is for USBs right?

Comment: @Ramhound Can't I use a DVD?

Comment: Alright, verify if compatibility mode is disabled or enabled.  For your disk to work it should be disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound Compatibilty mode?

Comment: Yes; Compatibility Mode.

Comment: Did you select Verify Option in ImgBurn app? Did it verify the disk and then concluded that the burn was successful? Are you able to enter the BIOS/UEFI Firmware during start before any booting proceeds? Are there any external storage devices connected to any ports like USB in your system? Did the PC come with Windows 10 Pre-installed as OEM OS? Do you know if your system has UEFI firmware of Legacy BIOS firmware? If PC came with OEM Win10 is it 32/64 bit and what 'bitness' Win10 you have downloaded? 32 or 64 bit ?

Comment: @pat2015 No the disk didn't verify I got an error...Yes I can enter BIOS during start...No external storage devices....No it didn't come with Windows 10 pre installed...I dont know if my system has UEFI firmware of Legacy BIOS firmware ..I downloaded 64 bit Win 10

Comment: Can you  extract the downloaded ISO using suitable app that can handle ISO files e.g. 7zip. If extraction fails in the first place, you have data corruption during download. I suggest while burning you set Verify ON and get a successful burn & successful data verification notification. Do you know any further specs of your PC, mostly the motherboard make/model if it's retail?

Comment: @pat2015 I did put Verify on but I got an error..I guess burning was not yet succesful?

Comment: You can not burn Windows 10 ISO on a CD. CD had only 700MB capacity whereas Windows 10 DVD is in excess of 3 GB. Since you got some error it's highly likely that you have burn errors resulting in bad disk. Were you able to fully extract ISO file to a folder? I suggest you try alternative software like say BurnAware Free and burn the image at a lower speeds. Alternatively as already suggested you can opt for USB booting using Rufus.

Comment: @pat2015 I will try to burn it again using a different software ( other than imgburn )..Thank you so much Pat!